# How can you log HTTP responses in node?

Tags: node.js

You can use `NODE_DEBUG=http` to log requests, is there a similar way to log responses?

Comment: Can you show your relevant code and describe exactly what you're trying to log?  As best I could find last time I looked into this, there is no built-in http logging for the body of an http request or response.

Answer (score 0):

```
const logRequestStart = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.info(`${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}`)
    next()
}

app.use(logRequestStart)
```

[click here](https://brightinventions.pl/blog/http-request-logging-in-node/)

Comment: He want to log the **response** not the **request**